# How to register a handler in web.config for iis7

Tags: asp.net, web-config, httphandler, ihttphandler

I had to 301 redirect some htm pages. I am trying to do it via `HttpHandler`. This website dosen't use any namespace.
I created a test handler as follows:

```cs
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="htmlhandler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class htmlhandler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write(url);
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

In `Web.config` I tried to register the handler as follows:

```xml
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*.htm" type="htmlhandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'htmlhandler' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Please help. My handler is placed in `App_Code` folder but still the server is unable to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `<add verb="*" path="*.htm" type="htmlhandler, assemblyName"/>`.

Also `<system.webServer>` is valid only if you running the App Pool in Integrated mode. Check if you are running the App Pool in Integrated or Classic mode.

Comment: yes <system.webServer> problem is solved, thankx can you tell why my handler is not being called on production server which is on a shared server, but is working on local system.

Comment: Which version of IIS is being used for productions?

Comment: Its iis7 in windows2008 server. I talked to server people they do not allow handlers for resources other than .net native resources. Thankx for you help.